# Log Cleaning does not work

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, log, windows

I turned on Log Cleaning (under System -> Configuration -> System -> Log Cleaning). This is my configuration:

[image: Log Cleaning Configuration]

I set a Scheduled Task (I'm on Windows) to send a request to `cron.php` every 5 minutes. But nothing happens. I checked `cron_schedule` table and it didn't scheduled either. I also checked `log_quote` (and other `log` tables) and nothing cleaned.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 13):

Kick off the log cleaning yourself, manually (or set up in a CRON as I usually do):

```
Usage:  php -f log.php -- [options]
        php -f log.php -- clean --days 1

  clean             Clean Logs
  --days <days>     Save log, days. (Minimum 1 day, if defined - ignoring system value)
  status            Display statistics per log tables
  help              This help
```

So, to clean the log fully pass the flag option `clean` with a number of days to clean:

```
php -f shell/log.php clean --days 7
```

Comment: It's great but I'm not just cleaning Magento logs. I want to clean my custom module log messages so I was observing the `log_log_clean_before` event.

Comment: Well that's a horse of a different color. Post your module code, sonny-boy! Any log clean event should fire from running the cleaner above - so you likely have an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I explained the situation http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/15210/4276. It was just a misunderstanding of time :)

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and log.php is not cleaning the tables. I used clean --days 7 and is not cleaning anything. Tables status is the same after cleanings. I guess this is a bug in Magento. I truncated all tables mentioned in log.php file then I used this script again after one day. It is not working at all.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out. The problem was difference of timezones between Magento and Database. Mysql was GMT but Magento was set at +3.5 (Asia/Tehran). So There was no problem actually. If you reach this problem set the `Start Time` based on `Timezone` you set in Magento before, but remember that that time in database may be saved differently. And it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I empty the cron_schedule table, flush the cache and run cron.php again. Magento schedules it's cron tasks in advance. How much exactly is configurable in system config > Advanced > System > Cron. It says: 'Generate Schedules Every' 1440 in my case and 'Schedule Ahead for' 1920. So either you'll have to wait for 1440 minutes before your changes take effect or you can empty your cron schedule table and flush cache to force rescheduling right away. I hope this works in your case.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I empty the table and the cache but log cleaning didn't schedule.