# CE 1.9.2.2 - log.php script is not cleaning log tables

Tags: log

1) go to magento root then in shell/ directory

2) execute "php -f log.php status"
(in my case Data size is 150 MB)

3) execute "php -f log.php clean"

4) execute again "php -f log.php status" for checking the cleaning action.
(it should show a decreased size from 150 MB, but it doesn't.

Well I truncated manually all the tables inside the databases and checking again the status it is decreased to 164 kb. This is a bug, this file is not cleaning the log tables. By the way I already reported in Bug List.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any message after third step?

Comment: there is no error message after step 3.

Comment: You should see "Log cleaned" message. If you don't see it, it means that script wasn't executed. Is there anything in error logs?

Comment: I get "Log cleaned". But checking the status it is the same. There are no errors in any log (php or magento).

Update I tried to use log.php clean --days 2000, but still no changes for 

- log_visitor
- log_visitor_info
- report_viewed_product_index
- report _event

I think I will make my own script in order to truncate correctly these tables. In my opinion this is a Magento issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer which worked for me: [Log Cleaning does not work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/log-cleaning-does-not-work)

```
php -f log.php -- clean --days 1
```