# Why cli command "$ php shell/logs --clean" didn't remove all logs data?

Tags: magento-1.7, cli, log-cleaning

2 times a year I clean my Magento logs (CE 1.7.0.2).
I run the process by cli:

```
$ php shell/log.php --clean
```

Usually it works fine. 
But today after the process ends the php shell/logs.php --status gave me 5GB were still into logs db tables (7GB before the cleanup).

It means only 2GB were removed.

I tried to run the process several additional times but it remains to 5GB...

Is anyone encountered the same problem?

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can clean these logs by using one of the three following methods:

1. Log cleaning in the Magento Admin
2. log.php in the ../shell directory
3. phpMyAdmin or MySQL client

**Log cleaning in the Magento Admin :**

The Magento system has a built-in for cleaning up log information. If you go to

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning
```

**log.php :**

You can either configure the shell utility **log.php**  as a cron job or run manually to clean on-the-fly.

From the Magento root directory, type the command:

```
php -f shell/log.php clean
```

**Manual cleaning with phpMyAdmin**

This is the most efficient way to clean the logs for those more comfortable working with databases. It is faster than the built-in Magento tools and it allows you to clean other tables not included in those tools. This procedure will consolidate the data inside those tables, often decreasing database size by as much as 95% and greatly reducing query times.

1. Open the database in phpMyAdmin from the SiteWorx control panel.
2. select the check box for the following tables:

   ```
   dataflow_batch_export
   dataflow_batch_import
   log_customer
   log_quote
   log_summary
   log_summary_type
   log_url
   log_url_info
   log_visitor
   log_visitor_info
   log_visitor_online
   report_viewed_product_index
   report_compared_product_index
   report_event
   ```

[image]

3. At the bottom of the page, from the With Selected list, and select
   Empty.
4. A confirmation screen will appear. Click **Yes**. This will truncate all
   of the selected tables.
5. Click the **Structure** tab at the top of the page.
6. Select the same tables as you did in Step 2, then under the With
   Selected list, select Optimize.

**Regular maintenance**

It is not unusual to see 2GB+ databases decrease their size by 75% after cleaning the logs. It is therefore critical to regularly perform this sort of maintenance, particularly if your time-to-first-byte latency begins increasing and you have already implemented the other performance tweaks.

Comment: I'm sorry but you absolutely don't answer to my question. I know how to clean up the logs. Look at my initial message, I'm already using the CLI method with shell/logs.php.

The weird point is: why the db tables are not completely cleaned after the process? Do you have an idea?

Comment: It may be time execution problem, So use use the following command to clean logs part by part. `php -f shell/log.php clean --days 7 `

Comment: I already tried with --days 1 but ok I'll give a new try with --days 7

Comment: Have a look at the http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95717/ce-1-9-2-2-log-php-script-is-not-cleaning-log-tables

Comment: Looks very similar to my case.

Comment: My suggestion is clean logs through the manual process. Then setup a cron job to clean logs.

Comment: Finally, after playing with --days, the size amount decreased... Thank you  Supravat for the dialog ;)